# Why are the both val box1 and val box2 correct in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I'm a beginner of Kotlin, the following code is from a webpage, the val box3 is correct.

and I was told that the both val box1 and val box2 are correct too. Why?

```
class Box<T>(val value: T)


val box1: Box<Int> = Box<Int>(1)

val box2: Box<Int> = Box(1)

val box3 = Box(1)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All of these three lines are "correct" and create the exact same instances the exact same way. They just use various levels of type inference that Kotlin provides (i.e. it can figure out the types and type arguments from the context on its own), from the most verbose first one to the most concise last one.

Since there is absolutely no difference in what these lines do, it's up to your preference to use whichever one is most readable to you.

Answer (score 2):

They are correct but not always same. Let go through them one by one.

```
val box1: Box<Int> = Box<Int>(1)
val box3 = Box(1)
```

The first one declares `box1` is `Box<Int>` while `box3` let the compiler to figure out what is its type. They are not always the same. 
Consider `Box<T>` implement an interface `IBox<T>`.

```
val box1: IBox<Int> = Box<Int>(1)
val box3 = Box(1)
```

box1 can be any object that implements IBox while `box3` is `Box<Int>`.

```
Box<Int>(1)
Box(1)
```

This is similar the one above. The first one declares explicitly and the second one let the compiler to figure out. Because `1` is `Int`, so the are the same. But also, this is not always true.

```
Box<Number>(1)
Box(1)
```

This make the first one a `Box<Number>` instead of `Box<Int>`

Comment: Good point that by giving an explicit type you can use something else than the inferred type. But the OPs three examples *are* the same which is what the question was about.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Kotlin is inferring the type based on what value you provide for the Box constructor. They're all valid because the compiler can figure out that the generic type `T` is going to be a type `Int`. There *might* be some optimisations in compile time if you are more explicit but I think it's mostly just a matter of preference.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor's value parameter `1` has the type `T`, and `Box<T>` has the same type parameter `T`.

The compiler knows that `1` has the type `Int`, so
`T` = `Int`, so that `Box(1)` = `Box<Int>(1)`.

The type of `Box<Int>(1)` is `Box<Int>` trivially, so both `box2` and `box3` have the type `Box<Int>`.